# get queryString of a URL on FreeMarker

Tags: java, freemarker

learning FTL here.

I'm trying to get add a query string on my FTL page, like `http://localhost/search`, i'd like to add a query string on the URL, say `http://localhost/search?bing` so that user could switch with the default setting when there is no query string.

However, I have no luck on grabbing the queryString from the URL. 
I'm also trying to avoid using a JavaScript solution on this.

here's my code:

```
<#if RequestParameters.bing?exists >
    <#assign useServer = "http://www.bing.com">
<#else>
    <#assign useServer = "http://www.google.com">
</#if>

<h1>${useServer}</h1>
```

typing in the queryString into the url still returns `http://www.google.com` on the `h1`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For query string `?param1=abc&param2=123`, you can retrive params like below:

`${RequestParameters.param1`} & `${RequestParameters.param2}`

And also try `<#if RequestParameters.bing??>`

parameters are something that followed by
 < protocol >://< host >:< port >**?**< param1 >&< param2 >&..

for example in https://www.google.co.in/search?q=StackOverflow URL param name is **q** and value is 'StackOverflow'

Answer (score 5):

I figured out to use request.getParameter("param")

```
<#if (request.getParameter("param")?has_content && request.getParameter("param")?lower_case?matches("true"))>
    <#assign useServer = "http://bing.com">
<#else>
    <#assign useServer = "http://google.com">
```

Worked like a charm.

Comment: I am getting null evaluation for request. How to pass request?

Comment: Works well on Liferay 7.2

Answer (score 0):

I tried to check request parameters with first post's code:

```
<#if RequestParameters.bing??>
```

BUT nothing happened.
Then I checked `<#if RequestParameters.param1??>` then I got result.

I hope it helps someone.