# How to get HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse in FreeMarker?

Tags: java, request, response, freemarker

I just took over a freemarker project.
The controller classes extend the abstract class squirrel.web.SquProcessor, and use squirrel.web.PageData to transfer values.
But now, I want to use the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse in the controller classes.
How to get them?

Comment: maybe this give you an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372165/get-querystring-of-a-url-on-freemarker

Answer (score 1):

FreeMarker is unaware of servlets or HTTP (barring the included `FreemarkerServlet` that was added to ease migrating from JSP). You see in templates what the controller class has exposed to FreeMarker. Exposing highly technical things like servlet request/response object is not very clean; ideally the template should only get application-domain objects and some helpers to generate URL-s and such.