# request.getParameter is undefined in Application Display Termplate?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, freemarker, liferay-theme

I am using Liferay 6.2 and I am trying to read request parameters in my **Application Display Template (freemarker)** like this:

```
<#assign myvalue = request.getParameter("param")/>
```

But all I get is:

```
Error on line 5, column 1 in 10154#10194#11902
request.getParameter("param") is undefined.
It cannot be assigned to myvalue.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this ? The built-in editor itself and its code completion told me everything is fine ;)

Comment: Have a look at second answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372165/get-querystring-of-a-url-on-freemarker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pankaj Kathiriya was right :)

The answer is :

<#if (request.getParameter("param")?has_content && request.getParameter("param")?lower_case?matches("true"))>
    <#assign useServer = "http://bing.com">
<#else>
    <#assign useServer = "http://google.com">