# Keycloak access cookie and/or url query params inside freemarker template

Tags: freemarker, keycloak

I want to access to some info's inside keycloak freemarker template. There are two approaches I am thinking about. To set url parameters and read them inside freemarker template or to set this info to a cookie and access them inside the template.

I tried already to access url parameters as described [here](http://marcsquire.com/check-for-a-url-parameter-with-freemarker/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372165/get-querystring-of-a-url-on-freemarker). But both are not working. 
Keycloak data model doesn't provide any getters for current Url.

Is one of those approaches possible? How can I achieve my goal

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar problem, where I had to access query parameters in my custom keycloak login theme. (using Keycloak version 2.1.0.Final)

There was no query param passed to my login site.
But I found out that inside

```
org.keycloak.forms.login.freemarker.FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider
```

you can access the following query parameters:

- scope
- response_type
- redirect_uri
- state
- nonce
- client_id
- response_mode

That is possible by using

```
UriInfo uriInfo = session.getContext().getUri();
MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParameters = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
```

You can read the query param `redirect_uri` like this

```
String redirectUri = queryParameters.getFirst("redirect_uri")
```

To pass certain data to your template you must use

```
attributes.put("keyToData", dataForTemplate);
```

before your process the template by

```
freeMarker.processTemplate(attributes, Templates.getTemplate(page), theme);
```

Then in your template (e.g. template.ftl) you can access the provided data, for instance:

```
<#if keyToData!false == true> 
    ...
</#if>
```

Unfortunately I was not able to access custom query parameters passed to my keycloak `/auth` endpoint inside `FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider`.

Comment: Thanks, I did exactly this, actually for the redirect_uri. I had to create a custom login forms provider using the exact same code as FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider, I just added a line to set the redirect_uri value to the attributes, and just like that I had the value available in the template

Answer (score 2):

For keycloak v11, also should be suitable for other versions:

This piece of code will allow you to get all the hash keys (eg. of `url` object)

```
<#list url?keys as k>
  ${k}<br>
</#list>
```

next to it - for me it's `totpUrl` key with the current URL value

```
<#if url.totpUrl?last_index_of("from=login") gte 0>
  bla bla
</#if>
```

Hope this can help

Answer (score 1):

To get query parameters, I used Javascript, because I struggled way too much with free marker

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const myParam = urlParams.get('myParam');
    </script>
```

Hope it'll help someone